# Read text from file and correct it (commas and dots)[Java]

Tags: java, filereader

I have to correct text in the file. 

When is comma or dot I have to change to the correct position e.g.
"Here is ,some text , please correct. this text. " to "Here is, some text, please correct. this text."

I noticed that my code is not work properly. For dots he does not work at all, for commas before adds comma make space.
Do you have any hints?

```
FileReader fr = null;
 String line = "";
 String result="";
 String []array;
 String []array2;
 String result2="";
   // open the file
   try {
     fr = new FileReader("file.txt");
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       System.out.println("Can not open the file!");
       System.exit(1);
   }

   BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(fr);
   // read the lines:
   try {
     while((line = bfr.readLine()) != null){

         array=line.split(",");
         for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
           //if i not equal to end(at the end has to be period)
             if(i!=array.length-1){
             array[i]+=",";
             }
            result+=array[i];
         }
      //  System.out.println(result);

        array2=result.split("\\.");
         for(int i=0;i<array2.length;i++){
             System.out.println(array2[i]);
             array[i]+="\\.";
             result2+=array2[i]; 
         }
          System.out.println(result2);
     }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Can not read the file!");
        System.exit(2);
   }

   // close the file
   try {
     fr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println("error can not close the file");
         System.exit(3);
        }
```

Comment: I use the debugging mode in my development environment. Are you using a development environment? Netbeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ, there is quite a list on Wikipedia.

Comment: You want to remove the space before the comma?

Comment: Let's say your input `line` is `"Here is ,some text , please correct. this text. "`. What is the result from calling `array=line.split(",");`?

Comment: Can you use regex and String replace to achieve your goal? Split may not be a good idea if you want to deal with more than one symbols

Comment: to Nicholas 1. Yes I am using Netbeans.
to DejaVuSansMono 2.Yes I want to remove the space before comma if after comma is not space I want add space. The same to periods.
to Sizik 3.The result is array with words e.g This is, text
the result would be array of This is and text array[0]=This is    ,array[1]=text
to dragon66 4. I can not use regex I even did not hear about it. I can use replace method. I know that split may not be a good idea.

Comment: String.split() and String.replaceAll() have parameters that are regex themselves. What I was trying to say is to use String.replaceAll() instead of String.split().

Comment: Ok but replaceAll() only replace commas and periods. It will not help me. I have to correct all the commas and periods(delete space or add).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first assume you can use regex. Here is a simple way to do what you want:

```
import java.io.*;

class CorrectFile 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    FileReader fr = null;
    String line = "";
    String result="";
    // open the file
    try {
      fr = new FileReader("file.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Can not open the file!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(fr);
    // read the lines:
    try {
         while((line = bfr.readLine()) != null){
            line = line.trim().replaceAll("\\s*([,,.])\\s*", "$1 ");
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Can not read the file!");
        System.exit(2);
   }

   // close the file
   try {
     fr.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println("error can not close the file");
     System.exit(3);
   }
  }
}
```

The most import thing is this line: `line = line.trim().replaceAll("\\s*([,,.])\\s*", "$1 ");`. First, each line you read may contain white spaces at both ends. String.trim() will remove them if so. Next, taken the string (with white spaces at both ends removed), we want to replace something like "a number of white spaces + a comma + a number of spaces" with "a comma + a white space) and the same thing with "dot". "\s" is regex for space and "\s*" is regex for "zero or any number of space". "[]" represents character group and "[,,.]" means either a "," or a "." and the middle comma just a a separator. Here we need to escape "\" for String, so now we have "\s*([,,.])\s*" which means let's replace some arbitrary number of white spaces followed by either a "," or a ".", followed by arbitrary number of white spaces whit either a "," followed by one space or a "." followed by one space. The brackets here makes the elements inside it a capture group which serves the purpose of "saving" the match found (here either a "," or a ".") and we use it later in our example as "$1". So we will be able to replace the matches we found with either a "," or a "." whatever the match is. Since you need a space after comma or dot, we add a white space there make it "$1 ".

Now, let's see what's wrong with your original thing and why I said String.split() may not be a good idea.

Aside from you are creating tons of new String objects, the most obvious problem is you (might be out of a typo) used `array[i]+=".";` instead of `array2[i]+=".";`. But the most not so obvious problem is right coming from the String.split() method which actually includes white spaces for the String segments in your split arrays. The last array element even contains only a white space.

Comment: It works. Can I ask you to explain this sentence("\\s*([,,.])\\s*", "$1 "); ? This ,,. mean commas coma dots but the \\s*? ok \\s means space.